# Como ordenar corretamente uma tag <ui:repeat> do JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Tenho um código porem na visualização na view ele está saindo desconfigurado.

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">
            <h:form id="content">
                <ui:repeat value="#{mbProduto.resultado}" var="prod">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <h2>Leia Mais</h2>
                            <h:graphicImage library="images" name="familia.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" /><br></br>
                            #{prod.nomeProduto}<br></br>
                            #{prod.especificacaoProduto}<br></br>
                            #{prod.precoDeMetroVenda}
                            <p><h:commandButton class="btn btn-primary" role="button"
                                value="Quero este" /></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ui:repeat>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
```

estou utilizando o bootstrap nesse caso.
obrigado.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo discutida no Meta: [*Edição completas de perguntas*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2053/201) c/c @Patrick

Comment: Um print da tela, mostrando a desarrumação ajudaria @AndreMartins.

Answer (score 3):

olá como estou utilizando o bootstrap, então era apenas um erro de colocação de algumas tags segue como ficou o código.

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">
            <h:form id="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <ui:repeat value="#{mbProduto.resultado}" var="prod">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <h2>Leia Mais</h2>
                            <h:graphicImage library="images" name="familia.jpg"
                                class="img-thumbnail" />
                            <br></br> #{prod.nomeProduto}<br></br>
                            #{prod.especificacaoProduto}<br></br> #{prod.precoDeMetroVenda}

                            <h:commandButton class="btn btn-primary" role="button"
                                value="Quero este" />


                        </div>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
```

obrigado.